# How to implement angular 4 server prerendering in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, prerender, angular

I'm upgrading a ASP.NET Core project from AngularJS to Angular 4. Now that Angular Universal (a community branch) has been integrated into Angular itself, I would like to experiment with server prerendering.

Server prerendering with Vue 2 and ASP.NET Core is pretty elegant (e.g. http://mgyongyosi.com/2016/Vuejs-server-side-rendering-with-aspnet-core/).

Are there any similar examples or tutorials about integrating Angular **4** server prerendering with ASP.NET Core, avoiding any refactoring from Angular Universal samples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now we're a month further and MarkPieszak did an incredible job at putting together a starter template for exactly this: server prerendering of an Angular 4 app by using node.js on the server side.

I can now answer my own question by referencing this:

- [ASP.NET Core & Angular 4 with server-side prerendering](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal)

  This starter template runs a perfect example out of the box. It's well documented and more complete docs are on the current roadmap.
- [Angular AspnetCore Engine](https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/ng-aspnetcore-engine)

  The heart of what makes server prerendering possible on ASP.NET Core. I has a decent readme to get started from scratch.

Comment: Upvoted. Could you see my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306233/using-addtaghelper-in-asp-net-core-webapi-asp-net-prerendering

Comment: cannot understand how can I implement server side rendering using ASP.NET Core Web API and Angular 4. Please, see my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have this package/showcase for angular 4 asp.net core, it does show up some kind of server prerendering but, angular structurally doesn't wanta server to worry about client view/page and just ask data from server.

with this controller you can cut and make your way:
https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETCoreAngular4/blob/master/webapp/src/webapp/Controllers/HomeController.cs

with this controller, angular only ask for data and leave view part to itself:
https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETCoreAngular4/blob/master/webapp/src/webapp/Controllers/StaffController.cs

https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETCoreAngular4

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it will prove useful in other ways, but unfortunately not for the prerendering I'm after:
I really would want the entire angular view to be prerendered on the server side in the same way Angular Universal did this. This was done by using node.js on the server and by implementing two boot files; one for the server, and one for the browser once it takes control of the DOM.

I found a sample of a similar endeavor [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42873506/angular-4-rc-4-and-net-core-server-side-prerendering?rq=1), but this user also seems to be stuck.

Comment: Seems like JavascriptServices now has [an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/800) open to upgrade to angular 4, it includes pre-server rendering. Keeping an eye on this one!