# Using @addTagHelper in ASP.NET Core WebAPI. ASP.NET Prerendering

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing **"ASP.NET Core Web API"** with **"Angular 4"**. And this is my usual approach to use "Web API" template, so there are no folders such as `Views`.

It was not a problem till I wanted to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices`. I am following this [tutorial of Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices Server Side Prerendering](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices#server-side-prerendering) and there are two important steps to use power `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices`:

1. go to your `Views/_ViewImports.cshtml` file, and add the following line:

   `@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices"`
2. Choose a place in one of your MVC views where you want to prerender a SPA component. For example, open `Views/Home/Index.cshtml`, and add markup like the following:

   `<div id="my-spa" asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/boot-server"></div>`

But Web Api does not have `Views` folder and I cannot do above steps?

So my questions are:

- How is it possible to use `@addTagHelper` in `ASP.NET Core Web API`?
- If it is not possible to use `@addTagHelper` in WebApi, is there any replacement for `@addTagHelper` in ASP.NET Web API?
- What should I do instead of using `@addTagHelper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag Helpers render custom tags within Views, if you don't have a view there is no requirement for a tag helper or View to contain it. I you need to return html, you will probably need to return that via the API and create your own code to generate Html?

Comment: Do you mean send HTML from controller action?

Comment: I am not 100% on what you're asking here, but if you are using a controller action without a view (i.e. API to return data) I am not sure how tag helpers are going to help as these are for rendering html.

Comment: My goal is using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices Server Side Prerendering` in `ASP.NET Core Web API`, not in `ASP.NET Core MVC`. So I do not know what I should do further without `Views` in Web API.